# Whether raman spectroscopy is dependent on crystallographic orientation

Tags: scattering, crystals, raman-spectroscopy

If I have three bars of Si, and each has the (100) (110) and (111) surface pointing up at the laser respectively, will I get a different raman spectra for each of them? In my opinion, I shouldn't because the vibrational states that are defined by the quantum harmonic oscillator, take into account all the existing planes and possible vibrational degrees of freedom, but I have never tried it practically so I wouldn't know.

Comment: So, in your opinion, the phonon spectra vs $k$ are isotropic?

Comment: No, they are definitely not but does the laser probe only the crystallographic direction that is oriented at the laser?

Comment: You have to match energy and momentum in the scattering event. If the phonon energy varies with momentum between crystal orientations, well, you would expect to match differently.